# TfidfVectorizer on large corpus with generators

Tags: python, scikit-learn, generator, corpus, tfidfvectorizer

I have large corpus splitted into 5K files , I am trying to generate a IDF based vocabulary using TF-IDF trasform.

Here is the code: Basically I have a iterator which loops through a directory for .tsv files, reading each file and yield.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def make_corpus():
    inputFeatureFiles = [x for x in os.listdir('C:\Folder') if x.endswith("*.tsv")]
    for file in inputFeatureFiles:
        filePath= 'C:\\' + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".tsv"
        with open(filePath, 'rb') as infile:
            content = infile.read()
            yield content 

corpus = make_corpus()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',use_idf=True, max_df=0.7, smooth_idf=True)

vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

This generates below error :

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.pyc in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    809             vocabulary = dict(vocabulary)
    810             if not vocabulary:
--> 811                 raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"
    812                                  " contain stop words")
    813 

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

I also tried this :

```
corpusGenerator= [open(os.path.join('C:\CorpusFiles\',f)) for f in os.listdir('C:\CorpusFiles')]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',use_idf=True,smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=True, input="file", min_df=1)
feat = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpusGenerator)
```

and get below error:

```
[Errno 24] Too many open files: 'C:\CorpusFiles\file1.tsv'
```

what is the best way to use TFIDFVectorizer on large corpus? I also tried appending a constant string to each yield string to avoid the first error but that also did not fix it. Appreciate any help !

Comment: While debugging the TfidfVectorizer it works. But when I try calling it as a function, it throws same exception

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, recently I have also studied the same question. And according to my experience, maybe you can try the follow demo codes:**

```
import glob
all_files_path = glob.glob(path_to_the_dir_of_your_data_files)

def fit_iterator():
    for file_path in all_files_path:
        with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            for line in file:
                yield line # please make sure that line is a instance of str
                           # representing a single sample.

corpus = fit_iterator()
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(corpus)
```

**Good luck!**